# Plotting disconnected entities with shapely descartes and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, shapely, descartes

I need to plot a list of disconnected circles which I have created for other purposes in shapely.

I was trying to do exactly as the example in http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#cascading-unions shows (see [code](http://toblerity.org/shapely/code/cascaded_union.py)) but that works only if the circles overlap and the overall thing is connected (which is not in my case). As you can see by replacing the line

```
polygons = [Point(i, 0).buffer(0.7) for i in range(5)]
```

with

```
polygons = [Point(i, 0).buffer(0.7) for i in (0,4)]
```

that breaks with and `AssertionError` for the thing not being a Polygon by descartes (or by matplotlib failing `assert vertices.ndim == 2` if one comments out the descartes assertion as a test)

Looking at the docs for [matplotlib.path.Path](http://matplotlib.org/api/path_api.html#matplotlib.path.Path) it seems possible to use MOVETO to achieve this goal, but shapely does not seem to support it. Is this correct? What workarounds do I have?

Comment: Can't you just plot all the circles one after another?

Comment: @DavidZwicker That is what I am doing right now, but it's unsatisfactory because i) there are too many circles and ii) I don't care about each one, but I care about the covered area, so a plot like b) of the shapely example would be perfect

Answer (score 5):

The following code works:

```
from shapely.ops import cascaded_union
from shapely.geometry import Point
import random
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np

circles = [Point(random.random(), random.random()).buffer(random.random() * 0.1) 
            for i in range(100)]

polygons = cascaded_union(circles)

fig, ax = pl.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))

for polygon in polygons:
    mpl_poly = Polygon(np.array(polygon.exterior), facecolor="g", lw=0, alpha=0.4)
    ax.add_patch(mpl_poly)

ax.relim()
ax.autoscale()
```

the output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This gives some clues, and it works in your example but it's still obscure. In particular, if/when there are so many circles for the figure to become connected, the `for polygon in polygons:` fails with a `TypeError: 'Polygon' object is not iterable`. I guess I can check if polygons is iterable and use the PolygonPatch approach when it isn't, but that seems so ugly.