# Creating Points from Coordinate-Tuple-List with shapely

Tags: python, geospatial, geo, shapely

I have a coordinates list looking like so

```
myCoordinates
> [(2, -6), (21, 19)]
```

I want to convert them into `shapely geometry` objects so that I can do some calculations with them:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
for i in myCoordinates:
    c = [Point(i[0], i[1])]

print c
> [<shapely.geometry.point.Point object at 0x1044033d0>]
```

However, that only gives me one (!) geometry object.

But when I do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27574897/plotting-disconnected-entities-with-shapely-descartes-and-matplotlib)

```
circles = [Point(random.random(), random.random()).buffer(random.random() * 0.1) for i in range(3)]
```

I get three geometry objects.

```
print circles
> [<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x1043f6890>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x10442f8d0>, <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x10442f910>]
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is it only converting one Point into a geometry object and not the two in my list?

Comment: Are you assigning all the points to `c` only in the for loop? `c = [Point(i[0], i[1])]`

Comment: @AKS what do you mean by that? I thought I replaced the random number creation in the example i linked with my "real" coordinates. I only left out the buffer...

Comment: What I mean is that when you say _that only gives me one (!) geometry object._ which variable is pointing to that object?

Comment: @AKS I edited my question. Included the `print output` from `c` and `circles`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are overwriting your variable in each iteration of the loop. You need to make `c` a list and then append to it:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
c = []
for i in myCoordinates:
    c.append([Point(i[0], i[1])])

print c
```

Or you can do it all in one line with a list comprehension:

```
c = [Point(coord[0], coord[1]) for coord in myCoordinates]
```

Comment: Your list comprehension loops over `coord` but uses `i` ;)

Answer (score 2):

Following would give you three points:

```
c = [Point(i[0], i[1]) for i in myCoords]
```

It follows the same list comprehension as the `circles`:

```
circles = [Point(random.random(), random.random()).buffer(random.random() * 0.1) for i in range(3)]
```

What you were doing earlier is assigning the point to a variable `c` so at the end of the for loop, there is just one point in a list:

```
for i in myCoordinates:
    c = [Point(i[0], i[1])] # here c is overwritten in each iteration
```