# Draw circles and test overlap with polygons in shapely

Tags: python, matplotlib, polygon, rectangles, shapely

I followed [Adrien's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66524608/create-a-list-of-rectangles-from-a-flat-list-of-coordinates-in-shapely) to create a graph that can have multiple polygons.

I plan to create filled-up circles that span across the whole grid in the graph. I want to test if there's **overlapping between the circles and the polygons** to identify which polygons overlap for each circle. To that end, I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27574897/plotting-disconnected-entities-with-shapely-descartes-and-matplotlib), but the circles here are cascaded whereas I want separate circles like [this](https://ibb.co/TvZGLFH).

How do I create circles and test overlap?

Any suggestion would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like that (even if there is always a better solution than nested loops):

First initialize a DataFrame that we will then fill with combinations of intersected rectangles/circles.

Then we will loop over the rectangles stored in `your_dict` and create circles based on `positions`.

For each circle, check if it intersects the given rectangle. If so, save the circle geometry in list.

When all circles have been checked, create a DataFrame with two columns, rectangle where the rectangle geometry is duplicated as many times as the number of intersected circles, and circle, where the circle geometry intersecting the rectangle is stored.

Finally, append this DataFrame to `results`.

```
results = pd.DataFrame()

for key,your_polygon in your_dict.items():
    
    intersected_circles = []
    
    for x in positions:
    
        for y in positions:
            
            sampleCircle = Point(x,y).buffer(1)
            
            intersect = sampleCircle.intersects(your_polygon)
            
            if intersect:
                
                intersected_circles.append(sampleCircle)
                
    to_append = pd.DataFrame({'rectangle': np.repeat(your_polygon, len(intersected_circles)),
                             'circle': intersected_circles})
    
    results = results.append(to_append, ignore_index = True)
```

A snippet of the first 10 lignes of `results` :

```
 rectangle                                             circle
0     POLYGON ((0 7, 4 7, 4 12, 0 12, 0 7))  POLYGON ((2 7, 1.995184726672197 6.90198285967...
1     POLYGON ((0 7, 4 7, 4 12, 0 12, 0 7))  POLYGON ((2 9, 1.995184726672197 8.90198285967...
2     POLYGON ((0 7, 4 7, 4 12, 0 12, 0 7))  POLYGON ((4 7, 3.995184726672197 6.90198285967...
3     POLYGON ((0 7, 4 7, 4 12, 0 12, 0 7))  POLYGON ((4 9, 3.995184726672197 8.90198285967...
4     POLYGON ((0 7, 4 7, 4 12, 0 12, 0 7))  POLYGON ((6 9, 5.995184726672197 8.90198285967...
5     POLYGON ((7 1, 10 1, 10 8, 7 8, 7 1))  POLYGON ((8 1, 7.995184726672197 0.90198285967...
6     POLYGON ((7 1, 10 1, 10 8, 7 8, 7 1))  POLYGON ((8 3, 7.995184726672197 2.90198285967...
7     POLYGON ((7 1, 10 1, 10 8, 7 8, 7 1))  POLYGON ((8 5, 7.995184726672197 4.90198285967...
8     POLYGON ((7 1, 10 1, 10 8, 7 8, 7 1))  POLYGON ((8 7, 7.995184726672197 6.90198285967...
9     POLYGON ((7 1, 10 1, 10 8, 7 8, 7 1))  POLYGON ((8 9, 7.995184726672197 8.90198285967...
10    POLYGON ((7 1, 10 1, 10 8, 7 8, 7 1))  POLYGON ((10 1, 9.995184726672196 0.9019828596...
```

Comment: You are a godsend!

Comment: Thank you very very much!  I am confused about ** ignore_index = True**. If possible please explain this. With np.repeat are you repeating something here? Also, will, it be possible to show all the circles in the graph with the rectangles?

Comment: Actually, for a specific circle if that circle intersects many polygons will this be able to capture it? I think all the circles should be for looped and then for each circle, all the polygons should be checked for intersection...

Comment: 'ignore_index = True' is there to create normal increasing indexes, and drop those from the initial DataFrame. Without it we would have indexes starting from 0 for each new DataFrame appended.

Comment: Each rectangle is checked with all circles, so all combinations are found. If one circle intersects several rectangles, then it will be detected for each of them and added in the DataFrame.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't understand how you are finding out all possible combinations of rectangles intersecting with each circle- I am saying that maybe the information is there in results but how do I extract this information?

Comment: Thank you ! I wrote a code myself...thanks again without you couldn't have done it ..thanks a billion!

Comment: Each rectangle/circle combination corresponds to one line. To find all circles intersecting a given rectangle, just look for the different apparition of that precise polygon in the rectangle column!